# Divide load among two UPS

Tags: inverter

I have two different UPS of different ratings. Currently I am only using one of them, but lately I have been thinking to add another one so that more load can be added and they can share the load.

Here is the circuit, do you think can work?

`b1, b4 & b5` will be directly using mains and no UPS

`b2 & b3` will be powered though `Inverter 1 (or UPS 1)`

`b6 & b7` will be powered though `Inverter 2 (or UPS 2)`

[image: circuit]

> Please note wherever its mentioned Inverter, I mean [UPS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uninterruptible_power_supply) (which is a more appropriate technical term)

Comment: I don't understand in this scenario where you have a "mains" that can offer enough power, and b1, .. b7 that can work with that mains, why you would need inverters at all – all this makes no sense. When we say "mains", we mean "line power", and that's AC everywhere, still you're connecting it to the DC input of your inverters? Like, I'm afraid you'll explain in much detail what the job of the inverters is here, or what your "mains" actually is, or maybe your "inverters" aren't just inverters: As it stands now, none of this does anything but damage the inverters.

Comment: @sudo:  Are your inverters used to stabilize the AC?  Do you live in an area where the AC voltage varies a lot?

Comment: I live in an area where ac voltages varies a lot also have very frequent power cuts (10 times a day; total outage a day is like 5-7hrs), now I have some appliances (b1, b4, b5) which needs heavy power like AirCon or Heater which I will route via Inverter are like LED bulbs, TV, mobile charging points etc.

So the main use of the inverter is to charge the Lead Acid Battery when there is power on the mains, and once there is power cut can provide AC supply to those outlets

For this, I already have `Inverter 1` working for over a 1yr, now I want to add 1 more inverter to help with more load

Comment: Are the inverters battery chargers, or do they just stabilize the AC?  The name "inverter" you are using means different things in different places.  The way you are using it seems obvious to you, but to those who know other meanings it is not clear what your inverter does.

Comment: An inverter can be: 1. A device to convert DC from a battery to AC for appliances. 2. A frequency converter to drive AC motors at different speeds. 3. A device to invert a logic level signal to change a high to a low. 4.  What ever it is that **your** inverters are doing.

Comment: Your diagram shows DC to AC converters (or vice versa) - the DC side cannot connect to AC.

Comment: by Inverter I mean, a device which is connected to a 12v DC Battery and also connected to mains power, and the device will charge the battery until charged completely or until there is power input. Once the mains input power is cut off, then it will start outputting AC by converting DC-AC from the connected battery. Connection wise, it has input AC point (2 wire), also has one point which connects to the battery (2 wire) and the 2 wire for output. Here in the circuit we are using only live output wire since both inverter and load are on same neutral wire (hence saving some wire)

Comment: OK.  That begins to make sense.  What you are talking about is an [uninterruptible power supply.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uninterruptible_power_supply)  It does contain an inverter, but it also has a battery and a charging circuit.

Comment: Yes that is correct, I am sorry for confusion, when I say Inverter, I mean UPS

Comment: Of course you can have two UPSes and plug different things into each UPS